# How to change RelativePanel attached properties in Windows Apps?

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, attached-properties, uwp-xaml

I have tried to change the RelativePanel attached properties of a control by XAML in the VisualState.Setters in a Visual State but the properties do not change, so I created a dependency property to test by code behind and neither.

Is there any way to refresh to a new group of values like:

```
 <VisualState.Setters>
      <Setter Target="TimestablesControl.RelativePanel.RightOf" Value=""/>
      <Setter Target="TimestablesControl.RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel" Value="false"/>
      <Setter Target="TimestablesControl.RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel" Value="true"/> 
 </VisualState.Setters>
```

And make the view more 'responsive'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For changing values of Attached Properties in Setter.Target use this format:

```
TargetObjectXName.(ClassName.AttachedPropertyName)
```

In you case:

```
 <VisualState.Setters>
      <Setter Target="TimestablesControl.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="Control1"/>
      <Setter Target="TimestablesControl.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel)" Value="False"/>
      <Setter Target="TimestablesControl.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel)" Value="True"/> 
 </VisualState.Setters>
```

Where "Control1" is the x:Name of the control you want to place left of TimestablesControl.

Comment: Yes it works, I tested with: <Setter Target="DayDetailsView.(RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel)" Value="False"/>
                        <Setter Target="DayDetailsView.(RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel)" Value="True"/>